# Sparql query syntax error on Virtuoso while querying Linked Geo Data Endpoint

Tags: rdf, sparql, endpoint, virtuoso, rdfs

I'm trying to query some basic SPARQL on Linked Geo Data's Endpoint  http://linkedgeodata.org/sparql

Running a normal Select * 
[image: Select * query]

i get a few triples like these [image]

But when i run

`#Prefix lgdr:<http://linkedgeodata.org/triplify/>
  #Prefix lgdo:<http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/>
Select ?subject  ?predicate ?object
 { lgdr:?subject ?predicate ?object .} 
Limit 200` `

I get :

[image]

Why is this happening ?

Comment: `#` is the comment character in SPARQL.  You commented out your prefixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as the namespace issues,  `lgdr:?subject ...` is not proper SPARQL.

It will be seen by the parser as the 4-tuple:

```
lgdr:   ?subject ?predicate ?object .
```

which is why it complains about `lgdr:`

Answer (score 3):

You commented out the lgdr namespace but you are still usting it in lgdr:?subject. Thus virtuoso willl not know what to do because the lgdr namespace is not defined.